# How to prevent any file from uploading if a single file has error in multiple files upload

Tags: php

I have a multi file upload script that works fine, but I would like to prevent any file from uploading at all if any of the files attached has an error.

I use $error variable to hold the erros, and after checking each file in a for() I tried if($error == 0) {// Upload files}, the file without errors uploads, I don't want that. If there's a file with error, then don't upload any file at all.

```
for ($image=0; $image < $countFiles ; $image++) {
   if($checkFile == false) {
      $error = 1;
      $errorMSG = "— Invalid file attached";
   } else { $error = 0; }

   if(file_exists($FileToUpload)) {
      $error = 1;
      $errorMSG = "— Sorry file exists";
   } else { $error = 0; }

   // NOW AFTER CHECKING FILES AND THERE'S NO ERROR UPLOAD
   if($error == 0) {
      move_uploaded_file();
      // files without errors uploads and ones with error doesn't. I don't want to upload any attached files at all if one or more files has an error.
   }
}
```

Comment: Well then you need _two_ loops - the first needs to check if there weren’t any errors, and the second one only has to move the uploaded files, if there were none.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking the same, just thought there's a way to do it without leaving the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so

1. remove the `move_uploaded_file()` from the validation loop.
2. Set $error to 0 before starting the loop
3. Once you find an error terminate the loop, there is no point continuing
4. Do the move after the validation loop only if $error remains at zero, in its own loop.

Here is a sample piece of pseudo code

```
$error = 0;
for ($image=0; $image < $countFiles ; $image++) {
   if($checkFile == false) {
        $error = 1;
        $errorMSG = "— Invalid file attached";
        break; // stop the loop there is no point continuing
   }

   if(file_exists($FileToUpload)) {
        $error = 1;
        $errorMSG = "— Sorry file exists";
        break; // stop the loop there is no point continuing
   } 
}

// if $error remains at 0, we had no errors so do the move
if ( $error == 0 ) {
    for ($image=0; $image < $countFiles ; $image++) {
        move_uploaded_file();
    }
} else {
    // here you would send the error messages if they exist
}
```